# sessionScope in Jquery

Tags: xpages

I have a Panel with the following :

```
<xp:panel  disableTheme="true">
        <div id="mypdfdoc">
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mypdfdoc').PDFDoc( { source : 'pdftest.pdf' } );
            });
        </script>
</xp:panel>
```

In this case the source filename is pdftest.pdf.
How can I use the value stored in a sessionScope as source filename in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change your script block to an Output Scriptblock, you can use inline SSJS code like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
   <xp:this.value>
      <![CDATA[
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mypdfdoc').PDFDoc(
               { source : '#{javascript:return sessionScope.PDFName}' } 
            );
         });
      ]]>
   </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

**EDIT:**

This can be used for any CSJS, not only jQuery.